# How can I find via Git who deleted a couple of important files locally (hasn't been staged yet)

Tags: git

We have an automation machine that is accessed by multiple people. All the automation code resides in a repository and is updated using GIT.

Recently, I found a couple of important files missing. I did a "git status" and it shows me that the files have been deleted (red color) and not staged/committed. I can easily "checkout" these files and restore them to order.

However, before I do that, I need to find out who deleted these files. **What Git command can I use (or is there a different way?), to find out who deleted this file?**

I cant use "git diff" because these changes weren't committed to the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these changes were not commited under GIT, then GIT can't tell you who deleted it or not.

You could probably try to filter the people who could have done that by checking when the file was modified last (and who was working during that time).

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If the changes are made only in the local filesystem git doesn't track who changed them.
If you want to know which user (of the OS) changed that, your file manager could help you.